Play Console Warning due to instabug-reactnative package: Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version
Received a warning in the Play Console saying the following

Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible
version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a
backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user
security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new
app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core
library version dependency to avoid app crashes

I ran:

./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt


and got this:
+--- com.instabug.library:instabug-survey:11.6.0
|         |    +--- com.instabug.library:instabug-core:11.6.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10 -> 1.8.10 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2

This shows that instabug-reactnative (package which i'm using) uses play-core sdk. This is why the warning has occurred. But when I checked the package's build.gradle, i couldn't find the play-core dependency. I tried updating the package to the latest version and still the play-core sdk seems to be used in it. Can i do something about it other than using an alternative package. Somehow please help!
